(DDD) How to handle multiple events that have the same result
I encountered with one problem in DDD application.
For example I have two aggregates: Order and Item.
class Order {
...
public bool IsVerified {get;set;}

// other properties
// does NOT contain Items collection
...
}

class Item {
...

public Item(..., int orderId){

   OrderId = orderId;
...
   AddDomainEvent(new ItemCreatedEvent(this));
}

public int OrderId {get;set;}

// other properties
...
}

When new Item is created, it sends an domain event ItemCreatedEvent. There is a handler ItemCreatedEventHandler that changes Order aggregate state:
class ItemCreatedEventHandler : INotificationHandler<ItemCreatedEvent>
{
    public async Task Handle(ItemCreatedEvent @event)
    {
        var order= await orderRepository.GetByIdAsync(@event.Item.OrderId);
        order.IsVerified = false;
    }
}

The problem is when we create for example 10 Items at once for the same Order (Id = 3), each Item will trigger an ItemCreatedEvent that will be handled 10 times by the ItemCreatedEventHandler but the logic of handler will be the same for each a such event: take the same farm (Id = 3) and update the same field (order.IsVerified = false).
What can you suggest in such DDD situations ? Is it ok to handle multiple events in the example I have given ? Or probably some changes in aggregates are needed ?

Not really deeply familiar with DDD, but the natural thing to me would be to have an Event for Bulk-Handling. And if that's not possible but such events would happen in short succession, I'd debounce (i.e. not handle right away but accumulate until no more events for that "group" have arrived for x amount of time) and then bulk handle the result of that.

Unrelated: Including "What is the best way to ..." is a pretty sure way to get closed as opinionated. Stick with your title question of "How to". People will most likely answer with what they think is best anyway.

Same.... not the best with DDD.... But can't u just register <INotificationHandler as Scoped or to create your own manager that will create only one instance of ItemCreatedEventHandler per scope?

I'm not experienced in DDD, but there seem to be some issues with your design. The item handler is focused on order and actually modifies it. It would make more sense to specify an Item created for Order event and handle it with an Order handler. That way, you can coalesce redundant operations. It also makes more sense that way. You state that Order does not have a collection of items but that's just how you've implemented it. Conceptually an order absolutely had a collection of items and your implementation is just a detail. In fact it seems an item cannot exist without an order.

I've some experience with DDD. I would think about which business rule you're going to implement in the handler. Then, according to that I would implement the handler. As Alan Haddad said, the design looks strange.

On the other side, if you're business rule requires this logic, as long as running the code several times (hence managing multiple events) does not break the domain, I don't think it's a problem. That means, the design looks strange, but it could be correct for you're set of business rules.

@LucaMasera The rule is when a new item is added to the order it's state/flag IsVerified  should be changed. The problem is when 10 items are created and added to the order at once, then the handler will process 10 times the same operation. (I updated the code example a bit)

First of all, given that you are following the DDD, I would think about how complex I would implement such a rule:
When an Item is created, the Order requires to be verified again
Then your could choose to do it:

simple: you add an Item, you fire an event, the handler modifies the Order. Super simple, it runs the same piece of code every time, but it's really simple to follow and it does what you expect.

complicated: you add some delay (how long?), or a kind of cache (how big?), and you fire a complex event when the delay is expired or the cache is full. But then, when you look at the code, you have to look deeply to understand domain.


While the first solution does exactly what the rule says, the second one add something that is written nowhere and it will require some time to understand why it has been implemented like this. Because it is written nowhere what to do with multiple Items. There is no mention about this aspect in the rule above.
Anyway, this sentence

The problem is when we create for example 10 Items at once

makes the things unclear. That is why I've wrote that your model looks strange. What I mean is:

would it be possible to to add X Items (you don't care if they are the same or not)?
would it be possible to add the same Item X times?

My rule above fits both (I wrote it according to what you have coded). But the second question add the possibility to extend (but even make it more complicated...), your domain model with a new entity. You could have something like a RepeatedItem (hence no cache or delays), where you create multiple times the same Item and you fire just a single domain event. But you pay the price of a more complex domain.
The question is: is this design giving a better representation of the domain or is it just polluting it with an useless entity?
Once you know better what you are going to model you could also find if the model needs to be extended or what you have is already enough.
For now, I can say to you that as long as the code respects the rule the best solution is to keep it as simple as possible. There is no mention about what do to with multiple items, hence handle the things in a simple way, as you have already done.
